# How to incorporate delay on a function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to implement a delay on a function. Should I wrap the function inside a delay function? Or can I somehow add more code, so that the animation doesn't start before 5 sec after page load?

```js
var typeThis = "blablablabla";
var displayText = "";

function type(fullString, typedSoFar) {
  if (fullString.length != typedSoFar.length) {
    typedSoFar = fullString.substring(0, typedSoFar.length + 1);
    document.getElementById("logoType").innerText = typedSoFar;
    setTimeout(function() {
      type(fullString, typedSoFar)
    }, 150);
  }
}

document.getElementById("logoType").innerHtml = typeThis;
var element = document.createElement('h2');
element.innerHTML = typeThis;
typeThis = element.textContent;
type(typeThis, displayText);
```

```html
<a class="navbar-brand" id="topper" href="#"><p id="logoType"></p></a>
```

Comment: have you tried using `setTimeout()` ? http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp

Comment: I've actually tried setTimeout(), but I'm not sure about how to combine it to my code? I'm still pretty new to javascript

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is `setTimeout`.

```
window.setTimeout(function () {
    type(typeThis, displayText);
}, 5000);
```

You can also add that to a listener to know when the window has finished loading:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function () {
    window.setTimeout(function () {
        type(typeThis, displayText);
    }, 5000);
});
```

**A full example:**

```js
var typeThis = "blablablabla";
var displayText = "";

function type(fullString, typedSoFar) {
  if (fullString.length != typedSoFar.length) {
    typedSoFar = fullString.substring(0, typedSoFar.length + 1);
    document.getElementById("logoType").innerText = typedSoFar;
    setTimeout(function() {
      type(fullString, typedSoFar)
    }, 150);
  }
}

document.getElementById("logoType").innerHtml = typeThis;
var element = document.createElement('h2');
element.innerHTML = typeThis;
typeThis = element.textContent;

window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  window.setTimeout(function() {
    type(typeThis, displayText);
  }, 5000);
});
```

```html
Waiting 5 seconds...
<a class="navbar-brand" id="topper" href="#"><p id="logoType"></p></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is not going to be adding more code to delay, but wrap this all in a Timeout: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout

Answer (score 0):

Use `setTimeout()` like so:

```
var timeoutID;

function delayedAlert() {
  timeoutID = window.setTimeout(slowAlert, 2000);
}

function slowAlert() {
  alert("That was really slow!");
}

function clearAlert() {
  window.clearTimeout(timeoutID);
}
```

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout